# CSS/SCSS - reusable mixin for custom attribute styles

Tags: javascript, css, sass, scss-mixins

I'm styling a re-usable popout component with an arrow positioned near the box. I'm wondering if there is a way to use a mixin to make the placement styling easier/neater?

```
.dialog {
    ...

    &[data-arrow-placement^='top'] {
        [data-arrow] {
            bottom: -12px;
        }
    }

    &[data-arrow-placement^='bottom'] {
        [data-arrow] {
            top: -12px;
        }
    }

    &[data-arrow-placement^='left'] {
        [data-arrow] {
            right: -12px;
        }
    }

    &[data-arrow-placement^='bottom-right'] {
        [data-arrow] {
            left: -12px;
            top: -12px;
        }
    }
}
```

I initially had a chain of @if being used however it seems like it would be adding more complexity than required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what else you want to do with this selector, I would either do like this:

```
@mixin arrowPlacement($placement) {
    &[data-arrow-placement^="#{$placement}"] {
        [data-arrow] {
            @content;
        }
    }
}

.dialog {
    $arrowPosition: -12px;
    
    @include arrowPlacement(top) {
        bottom: $arrowPosition;
    };
    
    @include arrowPlacement(bottom) {
        top: $arrowPosition;
    };
    
    @include arrowPlacement(left) {
        right: $arrowPosition;
    };
    
    @include arrowPlacement(bottom-right) {
        left: $arrowPosition;
        top: $arrowPosition;
    };
}
```

Or like this (you can even add a [`@content`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/mixin#content-blocks) if required):

```
@mixin arrowPlacement($placement, $position, $properties...) {
    &[data-arrow-placement^="#{$placement}"] {
        [data-arrow] {
            @each $property in $properties {
              #{$property}: $position;
            }
        }
    }
}

.dialog {
    $arrowPosition: -12px;

    @include arrowPlacement(top, $arrowPosition, bottom);
    @include arrowPlacement(bottom, $arrowPosition, top);
    @include arrowPlacement(left, $arrowPosition, right);
    @include arrowPlacement(bottom-right, $arrowPosition, left, top);
}
```

And if you don't plan to reuse the mixin, you can use the `-12px` position value directly instead of passing it as a parameter:

```
@mixin arrowPlacement2($placement, $properties...) {
    &[data-arrow-placement^="#{$placement}"] {
        [data-arrow] {
            @each $property in $properties {
              #{$property}: -12px;
            }
        }
    }
}

.dialog {
    @include arrowPlacement2(top, bottom);
    @include arrowPlacement2(bottom, top);
    @include arrowPlacement2(left, right);
    @include arrowPlacement2(bottom-right, left, top);
}
```

The [`argument list (...)`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/mixin#taking-arbitrary-arguments) will let you pass as many properties as you want.

Comment: I went with something along the lines of option 1. Its clean and simple, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?:

```
@mixin arrow($placement,$position,$other:'') {
    &[data-arrow-placement^='#{$placement}'] {
        [data-arrow] {
            #{$position}: -12px;
            @if $other != '' {
              #{$other}: -12px;
            }
        }
    }
}

.dialog {
  @include arrow('top','bottom');
  @include arrow('bottom','top');
  @include arrow('left','right');
  @include arrow('bottom-right','left','top');
}
```